# jQuery: selectors not working over ajax downloaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to extract an element from an ajax downloaded page to later append it to the DOM. I'm fetching the page like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: pagePath,
        success: function (data) { 
            //data is correctly shown in debugger, all the elements exist.

            var $div = $(data).find("[data-custom-attr]").first();
            //$(data) has lenght > 0, however $div has length 0!
            //$(data).find("#ajaxpage") also has lenght 0!
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
```

This is the fetched page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>      
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="ajaxpage" data-custom-attr="ajaxpage">
                <h2>Ajax downloaded page!</h2>          
            </div>      
        </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried with a few different selectors and everyone fails. I feel like there must be a really silly mistake somewhere in the code but can't see it.

What is the problem with those selectors?

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal It's in the question. Look at the comments :)

Comment: Try using `.load` instead? I.e. `$('#target').load('url/to/page.html [data-custom-attr]');`

Comment: no it won't, jquery throws away all the stuff up to and including the `<body>` tag, and everything including and after the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's likely it, as stated in the docs. Too bad some people don't read them thoroughly enough ;)

Comment: @MarcusEkwall:I dont see it in the question. comments says what he tried not what is the value of `data`

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Read again. `data is correctly shown in debugger, all the elements exist.`. This is true, since its a string that hasn't been run through `.innerHTML` yet, and thus the `html`, `head` and `body` tags are still present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that jQuery throws away all the nonsense you've given it, and only parses the div with h2:

```
$("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div id='ajaxpage' data-custom-attr='ajaxpage'><h2>Ajax downloaded page!</h2></div></body></html")
```

is exactly the same as

```
$("<div id='ajaxpage' data-custom-attr='ajaxpage'><h2>Ajax downloaded page!</h2></div>")
```

(jQuery's $("...") doesn't create full documents, it'll only build DOM fragments)

Since the first element is already your div, you cannot find `[data-custom-attr]` in its subtree, so the result will be []. If you do a `find("h2")`, that'll work fine, since it's in the subtree of your div, but you can't `find` the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $div = $('<div/>').html(data).find("[data-custom-attr]").first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $div = $('<div></div>').html(data).find("[data-custom-attr]").first();
```